# Extract $graphLookup matches into documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For context, I'm using MongoDB 3.6.4 and I'm trying to build a hierarchical schema for ACL permissions, but I'll boil the problem down and save the details.

Say I have a simple collection `C`, where `parents` is a list of references to other documents in `C`:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId
  parents: Array(ObjectId)
}
```

If I do an aggregation like:

```
[
  {
    $match: {_id: ObjectId("f00...")}
  },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "C",
      startWith: "$parents",
      connectFromField: "parents",
      connectToField: "_id",
      as: "graph"
    }
  }
]
```

I get back data like:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("f00..."),
  "parents": [ObjectId("f01..."), ObjectId("f02..."), ...],
  "graph": [<doc1>, <doc2>, <doc3>, ...]
}
```

Is there a way to split the `graph` items out into documents? e.g. from the previous output example:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("f00..."),
  "parents": [ObjectId("f01..."), ObjectId("f02..."), ...]
}
<doc1>
<doc2>
<doc3>
```

Comment: Should the `from: "C"` not read `from: "parents"`?

Comment: It is `from: "C"`. Documentation shows that this field is supposed to be the collection name. You can do a graphLookup on other collections.

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry, I didn't properly read that you had both parents and children in the same collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding below stages to query.

```
[
  {"$project":{"data":{"$concatArrays":[["$$ROOT"],"$graph"]}}},
  {"$unwind":"$data"},
  {"$project":{"data.graph":0}},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$data"}}
]
```

Comment: In this case, since there is only one root document, you need to wrap the {"_id": "$_id","parents":"$parents"} in [ ]. Mind making the fix and I'll mark you as the solution?
Side note: I simplified it to [["$$ROOT"], "$graph"]. I can remove the extraneous "graph" field later.

Comment: That is correct. You can use $project:{graph:0} to remove graph.